# Audit trail setting in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, audit-trail

I would like to know how to view the oracle 11g audit setting.

i need to check if it is enabled or not.

I read audit_trail will help but when i run the query "select * from audit_trail" it returns     invalid table error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the audit status via

```
SHOW parameter audit_trail
```

or

```
SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'audit_trail';
```

if it is set to `none` then auditing if off, anything else and it is on.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams017.htm#REFRN10006) for more information on the choices for this value.